# Accessing python dictionary with (?)multiple keys(?)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a large dictionary of values that I cannot sort. The only keys listed are "Spin_Up" and "Spin_Down". These correspond to a set of listed values. These values should have a second set of "keys" corresponding to an observation band. (Should have labels like "order 31")

I want to copy the values into a pandas data frame to save as csv or txt. How do I write/format this type of dictionary, and how do I access sets of values i.e. [1,2,3]

```
data = {"Spin_Up": [1,2,3] [4,5,6] [7,8,9],
        "Spin_Down": [10,20,30] [40,50,60] [70,80,90]}
```

Comment: Your definition of `data` is not valid Python.

Comment: `[1,2,3] [4,5,6] [7,8,9]` is not valid Python.  Is that supposed to be a list of lists?

Comment: It might be a list of lists, I was not aware of the correct name! I have over simplified my dictionary object for this example. Is it possible to have additional labels stored for my list of lists, inside of my dictionary?                                                                                                    For example, [1,2,3] and [10,20,30] both correspond to "order 31". Sets [4,5,6] and [40,50,60] correspond to "order 32". Could there be additional labels to access so I can cross check the order with the given python list?

Answer (score 1):

If you make the dictionary values into a list, you can reference them based on their index in the list:

```
data = {"Spin_Up": [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]],
        "Spin_Down": [[10,20,30], [40,50,60], [70,80,90]]}
```

```
>>> data['Spin_Down'][1] 
[40, 50, 60]
```